# PHP - Returning MySQLi Object form __construct method

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a `Connection` class which looks like:

```
class Connection{
    private $link;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->link = new mysqli("localhost","root","","myDatabase");
        return $this->link;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        $this->link->close();
    }

}
```

And I am trying to do this:

```
$link = new Connection();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `events`";
$query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
//Some stuff heref
$link->__destruct();
```

Is this not valid? I get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
<?php

class Connection{
    private $link;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->link = new mysqli("localhost","root","","myliveca_baikalpik");
    }

    public function connect(){
        return $this->link;
    }


}

$con = new Connection();
$link = $con->connect();


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `events`";
$query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
//Some stuff heref
$link->close();
```

> Note: The __construct method returns null by default. What you need
>   to return is the MySQLi Object.

Comment: *The __construct method returns the class itself* It is not actually true. `__construct` returns what is used with `return`, null by default.

Answer (score 3):

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

This is because `$link` is not actually an instance of `mysqli`; it is an instance of `Connection`.

You cannot return anything from the `__construct()`, as its purpose is only to build an instance of the `Connection` class itself, not to be a factory for *other classes*. The `return $this->link` does not do what you intended.

You have a couple of options.

You can make your class `extend mysqli`, wherein you are mostly just hard-coding the credentials and calling the `parent::__construct()` with them, and that eliminates the need for the `__destruct()` entirely:

```
// Merely extends mysqli, hard-coding your credentials
class Connection extends mysqli{
    // Your constructor has no params, and internally calls
    // the parent constructor
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct("localhost","root","","myDatabase");
    }    
}
```

The code you wrote to use this would then work immediately, but there isn't much added value, and I don't think this is really what you're going for.

#### Better option:

If you want to make a class which stores and manages a `mysqli` object, you can instantiate it but you cannot return it. You need to create a method to return it.

```
class Connection{
    private $link;

    // The constructor instantiates the mysqli
    public function __construct(){
        $this->link = new mysqli("localhost","root","","myDatabase");
    }

    // Other methods can operate on or manage the mysqli instance
    public function __destruct(){
        $this->link->close();
    }

    // Public accessor method to return the connection
    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->link;
    }
}
```

Then call the method to retrieve the connection.

```
$link = new Connection();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM atable";

// Call getConnection() to get the actual link
$query = mysqli_query($link->getConnection(), $sql);
$link->__destruct();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Return` within __construct is useless because `new` operator returns always instance of given class.

> To create an instance of a class, the new keyword must be used. An
>   object will always be created unless the object has a constructor
>   defined that throws an exception on error.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new

Also, try to avoid of calling magic methods directly.